# Alt-Gr + [Key] freezing XFCE on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS server

Tags: 16.04, server, shortcut-keys, xfce

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.5 server installation with XFCE**. Every time I hit `Alt-Gr` + `e` (Euro sign), `Alt-Gr` + `.` (ellipsis) and other combinations involving the right alt key, XFCE completely freezes. This occurs also when entering these just on the desktop. The only way to recover is switch to another `tty` and issue `sudo killall Xorg`, then restarting XFCE.

I found this thread on the Arch forums: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=218524

But the solution does not apply, since I start XFCE from `tty` via `$ xfce` with

```
$ cat .xinitrc

session=${1:-xfce}

case $session in
    i3|i3wm           ) exec i3;;
    xfce|xfce4        ) exec startxfce4;;
    # No known session, try to run it as command
    *                 ) exec $1;;
esac
```

So no meddling with dbus here. How can I start tracking the problem down?

** No, I don't want xubuntu since I need the longer LTS support of core Ubuntu on this machine.

Comment: All works fine using i3wm though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved when starting the `xfce-session` from the terminal via `startxfce4` directly instead of using `xfce` or `startx` with above `~/.xinitrc`file.

Note: Looking into `top` from another `tty` I gathered, that `xfwm4` received `SIGTTIN` upon pressing `Alt-Gr + [Key]`. To recover the session, one can therefore `pkill -CONT` from another `tty`.

Comment: It does also not occur when using `Nouveau` instead of `nvidia-390` video drivers on my Quadro 2000 (i.e. I can use `startx` and it still won't crash).

Comment: This resolved also an issue with awesomewm, although in my case I had to drop dbus-launch and launch awesome directly  instead from .xinitrc - I don't think I would have figured out this was related to signals, thanks chap.